# having trouble opening solution in source safe

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to open a solution file in source safe 6.0d in Visual Studio 2005 (no service packs installed) and I get the Conversion Wizard saying it was created in a previous version.

So I try to open it up in 2003 sp1 and it says it was created with a newer version of visual studio?

Is there a way to tell what version of Visual Studio is in Source Safe?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the .sln file. Starting with VS2005, the second line has an identifying tag, such as '# Visual Studio 2005'

Each project file also has a 'ProductVersion' attribute. My guess would be that some projects within the solution have already been converted to a newer version.